# Issue installing Package Provider on PowerShell 6

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Azure dev and trying to head started with PowerShell, however I'm struggling to install NuGet Package Provider.

```
PS C:\Users\dom> Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
Install-PackageProvider : Unhandled Exception - Message:'The type initializer for 'Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicType' threw an exception.' Name:'TypeInitializationException' Stack Trace:'   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicType.Create(Type tInterface, OrderedDictionary`2 instanceMethods, List`2 delegateMethods, List`1 stubMethods, List`2 usedInstances)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterface.CreateProxy(Type tInterface, Object[] instances)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterface.DynamicCast(Type tInterface, Object[] instances)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterface.DynamicCast[TInterface](Object[] instances)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterfaceExtensions.As[TInterface](Object instance)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletBase.get_PackageManagementHost()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletBase.SelectProviders(String[] names)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletWithProvider.get_SelectedProviders()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackageProvider.get_SelectedProviders()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletWithProvider.<get_CachedSelectedProviders>b__23_0()
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Extensions.DictionaryExtensions.GetOrAdd[TKey,TValue](IDictionary`2 dictionary, TKey key, Func`1 valueFunction)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Extensions.Singleton`1.GetOrAdd(Func`1 newInstance, Object primaryKey, Object[] keys)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Extensions.SingletonExtensions.GetOrAdd[TResult](Object primaryKey, Func`1 newInstance, Object[] keys)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletWithProvider.get_CachedSelectedProviders()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletWithProvider.GenerateDynamicParameters()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.AsyncCmdlet.<>c__DisplayClass83_0.<AsyncRun>b__0()'
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.PowerShel\u2026tallPackageProvider:InstallPackageProvider) [Install-PackageProvider], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnhandledException,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackageProvider
```

Has anyone seen this message before? Can any help?

I have run PowerShell in Administrator.

Many thanks,
Dom

Comment: check the links below may be you find answer  [link1](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/477)   and [link2](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/5089)

Comment: I followed that thread and it still doesn't work. I can see they mention manually adding the 'dll' so I'm going to try that next